# Object Orientation: How to Choose from a Number of Implementations

Tags: c++, oop, casting, polymorphism

I am a decent procedural programmer, but I am a newbie to object orientation (I was trained as an engineer on good old Pascal and C). What I find particularly tricky is choosing one of a number of ways to achieve the same thing. This is especially true for C++, because its power allows you to do almost anything you like, even horrible things (I guess the power/responsibility adage is appropriate here).

I thought it might help me to run one particular case that I'm struggling with by the community, to get a feel for how people go about making these choices. What I'm looking for is both advice pertinent to my specific case, and also more general pointers (no pun intended). Here goes:

As an exercise, I am developing a simple simulator where a "geometric representation" can be of two types: a "circle", or a "polygon". Other parts of the simulator will then need to accept these representations, and potentially deal with them differently. I have come up with at least four different ways in which to do this. What are the merits/drawbacks/trade-offs of each?

**A: Function Overloading**

Declare `Circle` and `Polygon` as unrelated classes, and then overload each external method that requires a geometric representation.

**B: Casting**

Declare an `enum GeometricRepresentationType {Circle, Polygon}`. Declare an abstract `GeometricRepresentation` class and inherit `Circle` and `Polygon` from it. `GeometricRepresentation` has a virtual `GetType()` method that is implemented by `Circle` and `Polygon`. Methods then use `GetType()` and a switch statement to cast a `GeometricRepresentation` to the appropriate type.

**C: Not Sure of an Appropriate Name**

Declare an enum type and an abstract class as in **B**. In this class, also create functions `Circle* ToCircle() {return NULL;}` and `Polygon* ToPolygon() {return NULL;}`. Each derived class then overloads the respective function, returning `this`. Is this simply a re-invention of dynamic casting?

**D: Bunch Them Together**

Implement them as a single class having an enum member indicating which type the object is. The class has members that can store both representations. It is then up to external methods not to call silly functions (e.g. `GetRadius()` on a polygon or `GetOrder()` on a circle).

Comment: Great questions.  OO is not the same as C++.  It's not about learning new keywords.  I highly recommend reading about OO, not C++ (unless the book uses C++ and hopefully other languages to teach you about OO).

Comment: @franji1 Thanks for your comment. Sorry if I did not make it clear, but I am indeed very aware that "OO is not the same as C++", and what I'm really trying to learn is how to think in OO terms. But at some point, concepts have to translate into code :-), and I use C++, hence the C++-specific question.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing more. "Other parts of the simulator will then need to accept these representations, and potentially deal with them differently" is a bit vague.

Comment: @Oktalist I'll try to answer that as well as I can at this stage. By "other parts" I mean a physics engine. 2D physics engines normally support circles and polygons, so for one thing, I will have a wrapper around the physics engine that depending on the type of representation, calls  the appropriate "AddObject()" method on the physical engine.

Comment: What percentage of the higher level code will be "common code" for both circles and polygons? Is it enough to be a real benefit for object oriented code in this case?

Comment: @rcgldr I will have some common code such as "GetArea()", "GetCentroid()", "GetPerimiter()", which will be implemented differently by the two classes, but can be overloaded. If that's not enough, would you go for function overloading?

Comment: Research the web for "object oriented class shape circle ellipse polygon".  There are different factions for whether ellipse should derive from circle or circle derive from ellipse.

Comment: @mga - It isn't clear to me what the goal of this program is or if it is a good candidate for learning C++ object oriented programming, which is why I asked about how much of the code (outside of the class) will be common code.

Comment: C. is sometimes handy. It knows less than `dynamic_cast` but it is faster and it doesn't require typeinfo that can increase binary size considerably. I use that pattern when I write a system and in the class hierarchy I provide I want to handle 1-2 classes specially. For example if you implement a stream interface and you also provide a memory stream implementation then by providing a `ToMemoryStream()` implementation in the base class you can perform optimizations in several places. Being able to "dynamic_cast" to some well known classes is handy but it is not a replacement for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of design rules (of thumb) that I teach my OO students:

1) any time you would be tempted to create an enum to keep track of some mode in an object/class, you could (probably better) create a derived class for each enum value.

2) any time you write an if-statement about an object (or its current state/mode/whatever), you could (probably better) make a virtual function call to perform some (more abstract) operation, where the original then- or else-sub-statement is the body of the derived object's virtual function.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
if (obj->type() == CIRCLE) {
    // do something circle-ish
    double circum = M_PI * 2 * obj->getRadius();
    cout << circum;
}
else if (obj->type() == POLY) {
    // do something polygon-ish
    double perim = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<obj->segments(); i++)
        perm += obj->getSegLength(i);
    cout << perim;
}
```

Do this:

```
cout << obj->getPerimeter();

...

double Circle::getPerimeter() {
    return M_PI * 2 * obj->getRadius();
}

double Poly::getPerimeter() {
    double perim = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<segments(); i++)
        perm += getSegLength(i);
    return perim;
}
```

In the case above it is pretty obvious what the "more abstract" idea is, perimeter. This will not always be the case. Sometimes it won't even have a good name, which is one of the reasons it's hard to "see". But, you can convert any if-statement into a virtual function call where the "if" part is replaced by the virtual-ness of the function.

In your case I definitely agree with the answer from Avi, you need a base/interface class and derived subclasses for Circle and Polygon.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like good advice. Could you please elaborate on your second point slightly? I'm not sure I fully get it yet. Perhaps a concrete example would help, if you have one?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you'll have common methods between the `Polygon` and `Circle`. I'd combine them both under an interface named `Shape`, for example(writing in java because it's fresher in my mind syntax-wise. But that's what I would use if I wrote c++ example. It's just been a while since I wrote c++):

```
public interface Shape {
   public double getArea();

   public double getCentroid();

   public double getPerimiter(); 
}
```

And have both `Polygon` and `Circle` implement this interface:

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
   // Implement the methods
}

public class Polygon implements Shape {
   // Implement the methods
}
```

What are you getting:

1. You can always treat `Shape` as a generelized object with certain properties. You'll be able to add different `Shape` implementations in the future without changing the code that does something with `Shape` (unless you'll have something specific for a new `Shape`)
2. If you have methods that are exactly the same, you can replace the interface with abstract class and implement those (in C++ interface is just an abstract class with nothing implemented)

Most importantly (I'm emphesizing bullet #1) - you'll enjoy the power of polymorphism. If you use enums to declare your types, you'll one day have to change a lot of places in the code if you want to add new shape. Whereas, you won't have to change nothing for a new class the implements shape.

Comment: Great answer, and I agree with all of that. However in my case some methods will still need to know what the general object is at a lower level, so they could instruct an (probably external) physics engine which representation to create. Unless for that purpose I use function overloading on Circle and Polygon directly?

Comment: @mga Can you elaborate, why "some methods will still need to know..."? I'm almost sure there is a way to avoid the need of this knowledge

Comment: @DenisItskovich In my case I need to instruct a physics library to create a representation of an object. The library will have its own representations for a circle and a polygon, which will be different to mine, but a circle will still need to be translated into a circle. Of course I could also achieve this by overloading an "AddObjectToWorld()" function on my physics library wrapper, with a version taking a circle and another taking a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Go through a C++ tutorial for the basics, and read something like Stroustrup's "The C++ programming language" to learn how to use the language idiomatically.

**Do not** believe people telling you you'd have to learn OOP independent of the language. The dirty secret is that what each language understands as OOP is by no means even vaguely similar in some cases, so having a solid base in, e.g. Java, is not really a big help for C++; it goes so far that the language [go](http://www.golang.org) just doesn't have classes at all. Besides, C++ is explicitly a multi-paradigm language, including procedural, object oriented, and generic programming in one package. You need to learn how to combine that effectively. It has been designed for maximal performance, which means some of the lower-bit stuff shows through, leaving many performance-related decisions in the hands of the programmer, where other languages just don't give options. C++ has a very extensive library of generic algorithms, learning to use those is required part of the curriculum.

Start small, so in a couple year's time you can chuckle fondly over the naïveté of your first attempts, instead of pulling your hair out.

Don't fret over "efficiency," use virtual member functions everywhere unless there is a compelling reason not to. Get a good grip on references and `const`. Getting an object design right is *very hard*, don't expect the first (or fifth) attempt to be the last.

Answer (score 0):

First, a little background on OOP and how C++ and other languages like Java differ.

---

People tend to use object-oriented programming for **several** different purposes:

1. *Generic programming*: writing code that is generic; i.e. that works on any object or data that provides a specified interface, without needing to care about the implementation details.
2. *Modularity and encapsulation*: preventing different pieces of code from becoming too tightly coupled to each other (called "modularity"), by hiding irrelevant implementation details from its users.
   It's another way to think about *separation of concerns*.
3. *Static polymorphism*: customizing a "default" implementation of some behavior for a specific class of objects while keeping the code modular, where the set of possible customizations is *already known* when you are writing your program.
   (Note: if you didn't need to keep the code modular, then choosing behavior would be as simple as an `if` or `switch`, but then the original code would need to account for all of the possibilities.)
4. *Dynamic polymorphism*: like static polymorphism, except the set of possible customizations is *not* already known -- perhaps because you expect the user of the library to implement the particular behavior *later*, e.g. to make a plug-in for your program.

In Java, the same tools (inheritance and overriding) are used for solving basically *all* of these problems.
The upside is that there's only one way to solve all of the problems, so it's easier to learn.
The downside is a sometimes-but-not-always-negligible efficiency penalty:  a solution that resolves concern #4 is more costly than one that only needs to resolve #3.

Now, enter C++.

C++ has different tools for dealing with all of these, and even when they use the same tool (such as inheritance) for the same problem, they are used in such different ways that they are effectively *completely different solutions* than the classic "inherit + override" you see in Java:

1. *Generic programming*: C++ `template`s are made for this. They're similar to Java's generics, but in fact Java's generics often *require* inheritance to be useful, whereas C++ templates have nothing to do with inheritance in general.
2. *Modularity and encapsulation*: C++ classes have `public` and `private` access modifiers, just like in Java. In this respect, the two languages are very similar.
3. *Static polymorphism*: Java has no way of solving this *particular* problem, and instead forces you to use a solution for #4, paying a penalty that you don't necessarily need to pay. C++, on the other hand, uses a combination of `template` `class`es and inheritance called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to solve this problem. *This type of inheritance is very different from the one for #4.*
4. *Dynamic polymorphism*: C++ and Java both allow for inheritance and function overriding, and are similar in this respect.

---

Now, back to your question. How would I solve this problem?
It follows from the above discussion that inheritance isn't the single hammer meant for all nails.

*Probably the best way (although perhaps the most complicated way) is to use #3 for this task.*

If need be, you can implement #4 on top of it for the classes that need it, without affecting other classes.

You declare a class called `Shape` and define the base functionality:

```
class Graphics;  // Assume already declared

template<class Derived = void>
class Shape;   // Declare the shape class

template<>
class Shape<>  // Specialize Shape<void> as base functionality
{
    Color _color;
public:
    // Data and functionality for all shapes goes here
    // if it does NOT depend on the particular shape
    Color color() const { return this->_color; }
    void color(Color value) { this->_color = value; }
};
```

Then you define the generic functionality:

```
template<class Derived>
class Shape : public Shape<>   // Inherit base functionality
{
public:
    // You're not required to actually declare these,
    // but do it for the sake of documentation.
    // The subclasses are expected to define these.
    size_t vertices() const;
    Point vertex(size_t vertex_index) const;

    void draw_center(Graphics &g) const { g.draw_pixel(shape.center()); }

    void draw_outline()
    {
        Derived &me = static_cast<Derived &>(*this);  // My subclass type
        Point p1 = me.vertex(0);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < me.vertices(); ++i)
        {
            Point p2 = me.vertex(1);
            g.draw_line(p1, p2);
            p1 = p2;
        }
    }

    Point center() const  // Uses the methods above from the subclass
    {
        Derived &me = static_cast<Derived &>(*this);  // My subclass type
        Point center = Point();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < me.vertices(); ++i)
        { center += (center * i + me.vertex(i)) / (i + 1); }
        return center;
    }
};
```

Once you do that, you can define new shapes:

```
template<>
class Square : public Shape<Square>
{
    Point _top_left, _bottom_right;
public:
    size_t vertices() const { return 4; }

    Point vertex(size_t vertex_index) const
    {
        switch (vertex_index)
        {
        case 0: return this->_top_left;
        case 1: return Point(this->_bottom_right.x, this->_top_left.y);
        case 2: return this->_bottom_right;
        case 3: return Point(this->_top_left.x, this->_bottom_right.y);
        default: throw std::out_of_range("invalid vertex");
        }
    }

    // No need to define center() -- it is already available!
};
```

This is probably the best method since you most likely *already know* all possible shapes at compile-time (i.e. you don't expect the user will write a plug-in to define his own shape), and thus don't need any of the whole deal with `virtual`.  Yet it keeps the code modular and separates the concerns of the different shapes, effectively giving you the same benefits as a dynamic-polymorphism approach.
(It is also the most efficient option at run-time, at the cost of being a bit more complicated at compile-time.)

Hope this helps.